# invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' CPP

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int static t[1000][1001];
int solve(int arr[],int i, int j)
{
    if(i>=j)
        return 0;
    if(t[i][j]!=-1)
        return t[i][j];
    int mini=INT_MAX;
    for(int k=i;k<=j-1;k++)
    {
        int temp=solve(arr,i,k)+solve(i,k+1,j)+(arr[i-1]*arr[k]*arr[j]);
        if(temp<mini)
            mini=temp;

    }
    return t[i][j]=mini;
}
int main()
{
    memset(t,-1,sizeof(t));
    int arr[]=[20,30,40,10,60,90];
    solve(arr,1,sizeof(arr))


}
```

the above code is of **MCM** in **Dynamic programming**

the error message I get Is invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'
what those this mean and how to resolve this error

Comment: It means you're using an `int` where an `int*` is expected; implicitly converting from an integer to a pointer is not valid. You resolve it by looking at the location of the error (always important to include in your question!) and not using an `int` there :)

Comment: Here is the problem `solve(i,k+1,j)`. `i` is an `int` but `solve` expects an `int *` as first argument.

Comment: Presuably you meant to write `solve(arr,k+1,j)` instead of `solve(i,k+1,j)`. That would at least compile.

Comment: int my `int main()` error shows as **expected identifier before numeric constant** at `int arr[]` part . what this means?

Comment: Should be `{ ... }` not `[ ... ]`.

Comment: Lucky use of memset

Comment: Also useless use of memset. Static variable are initialized to 0. And you can always use `= {};`if you want to make it obvious.

Comment: `sizeof(arr)` is not the number of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `solve(i,k+1,j)` is wrong - the `solve` function expects a pointer to `int` as its first argument which is expected to point to an array, but you just pass an integer `i`.